# hbase-client or hbase-common for HBase 0.94.6-cdh4.5.0

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We are using Cloudera CDH 4.5.0 for HBase and Storm 0.9.3 uses hbase-client. Unfortunately, it seems Cloudera did not provide an hbase-client maven artifact, and I cannot figure out how to satisfy the dependency for `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider`. According to the Maven search site, it can be provided by either hbase-client or hbase-common. Can someone tell me if there is a comparable version of either of these that I can use with cdh 4.5.0?

Comment: The hbase-client/hbase-common jars are only available for cdh5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using cdh4.x or cdh5.x? the hbase-client/hbase-common jars are only in cdh5 (hbase 96+). The cdh4 release has only one big hbase jar containing everything. Also UserProvider doesn't seems to be present in 4.5.0 but is present from 4.6.x
hbase-client depends on hbase-common, so in general you need both if you want to use client.

(if you are looking only for the UserProvider class that is in hbase-common)

Comment: That's the conclusion we came to as well. Fortunately, it's providing a strong case for moving up to 5.2.